# Conditional validation - 1 of 2 fields must be present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my app that I build to learn, I want to do a conditional validation where at least 1 of 2 fields must be present.

```
validates :key, presence: :true, if: "key_position.nil?"
validates :key_position, presence: :true, if: "key.nil?"
```

I followed the [rails validation guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation), yet don't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a `:` before `true`, which is wrong:

```
validates :key,          presence: true, unless: 'key_position.blank?'
validates :key_position, presence: true, unless: 'key.blank?'
```

or

```
validates :key,          presence: true, unless: ->(obj) { obj.key_position.blank? }
validates :key_position, presence: true, unless: ->(obj) { obj.key.blank? }
```

Comment: fixed the ': ' before the true; tx for noticing. Yet neither of the 2 works.

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter it is impossible. This is 1000% correct way(s) to do conditional validation. save your object with `save!` or `create!` and see if it's something else that's wrong

Comment: I know that is why I don't understand. I use `@tag.update(tag_params)` (save! does not work for some reason)

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter use `@tag.update!(tag_params)` and you'll see real validation issues

Comment: @AndreyDeinenko - with save! it does not save the changes

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter I **know** that. Your task to see why :) Meaning, read the exception message. And you will see, that these two validations work, it is something else that fail

Comment: no have not; am in the dark here :-( - validation works with a custom validation - just need good message

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter you do not need a custom one for conditional validation here, but if there is no way you can find out the problem otherwise. what does `@tag.update!(tag_params)` return?

Comment: am learning rails, so don't know yet how to find out what `@tag.update!(tag_params)` returns. You mean what the params are?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter no, it should raise errors if the `@tag` is not updated because of validations errors. I would like to see those errors. Just change it in controller (to using `!`), and  go through updating process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126117/discussion-between-dimitri-de-ruiter-and-andrey-deineko).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [custom method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) for semantic condition.

```
validate :at_least_one_of_key_or_key_position

private

def at_least_one_of_key_or_key_position
  unlsee key.present? || key_position.present?
    errors.add(:base, "at least one of key or key_position should exist")
  end
end
```

just another solution for you :)

Comment: and how would I add the message for the error notification? It now says please review the problems below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
validates :key,          presence: true, unless: :key_position
validates :key_position, presence: true, unless: :key
```